# How Avoid Muliple checkout of Componentes in AEM page other than Pagelock

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

My Requirement is like Build in a process to lock a component during content development or updation.
For example, Vivek can still publish a page with OLT update while another author is updating another component in the same page. The previous version (that is not being updated) will be published along with vivek’s updates. 
Since the User group is large & we have frequent updates we can't go for **Pagelevel lock**(multiple user will be working on the same Page).is der any Possible way to achieve this?... i hav tried the **"FieldEditlockMode"** but not works for me,am using AEM 6.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AEM Launches may satisfy your requirements, allowing your authors to edit components for future production releases without affecting an immediate release. Here is the documentation for 6.1:

- [Launches](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/site-page-features/launches.html)
- [Creating Launches](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/site-page-features/launches/creating-launches.html)
- [Editing Launches](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/site-page-features/launches/editing-launches.html)
- [Promoting Launches](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/site-page-features/launches/promoting-launches.html)